# Audio Drivers for HP 250 G4 Notebook PC

Tags: drivers, hp

I recently switched over to Ubuntu, but I have no sound.

Here is my [laptop model](http://www8.hp.com/au/en/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=7609933).

If I use `lspci` command I get :

```
Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
```

If I use pulseaudio I get :

```
E: [pulseaudio] ltdl-bind-now.c: No se pudo abrir el múdolo /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: /usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules/module-bluetooth-policy.so: clase ELF errónea: ELFCLASS647
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to open module "module-bluetooth-policy".
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Fallo al intentar iniciar el demonio.
```

Please tell me if it's possible to install some compatible driver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ca you type `pulseaudio` in the terminal and add the output to the post?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have completed the information

Comment: Spanish? Me no comprande Spanish. :D Anyways, it seems like the pulseaudio refuses to start. Let's try reinstalling, that is `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio`.

Comment: If I am correct, (which is what I realized now), the permissions are not set. Attach the output of `cd .config/pulse/ && ll`.

Answer (score 0):

solved

Thanks Tony Lancer.

I reinstalled pulseaudio with :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

My sound is working now.

If I use pulseaudio now I get:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Ha fallado pa_pid_file_create().
```

Do not know if that's a problem.

Thanks